# Drupal 7: How do I import a RSS feed?

Tags: drupal, rss, drupal-7

I have an RSS feed and I want to integrate each item into it as content. I already created a new content type, but I'm insure how to import the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) will allow you to import content/create nodes from rss.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Aggregator](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/aggregator) module to do it for you.
Good luck.